# Getting closest point on road to point in Google Maps using Python?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, google-maps-api

I need to find the closest point on a road to a external point. I need to do it without downloading the data (I don't know if this is possible in Google Maps) nor using PostgreSQL. I know some Python wrappers to Overpass for using OpenStreetMap, where is easy to use the function 'around', which is I need. But is possible to do the same for the free API of Google Maps?

I've asked a similar question in [Getting closest point on road to point in OpenStreetMap using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187687/getting-closest-point-on-road-to-point-in-openstreetmap-using-python), but with OpenStreetMap. What about Google Maps?

Comment: What do you mean by data? The background data provided by Google (geocoding, routing, etc.) or do you have your own files?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I known (and I'm newbie in this kind of tasks) that I can download the OpenStreetMap 'data' (vector information of reads, etc.), then convert it to a PostgreSQL database via osm2pgsql and then make my queries as a local user. But I need to do the queries via web, task that I can do via Overpass and some of its Python wrapper. Now I need to do the same in Google Maps and again I need to do it via web, without download any data nor transforming it to any database

Answer (score 1):

Since you downloaded the OSM data I would suggest you convert it to GeoJSON, so you can work with [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/), which accepts GeoJSON as input data.

To convert data to GeoJSON you can work with different tools, such as [geojson.io](http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0) or [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

Once everything is in GeoJSON you can use *turf.nearest* ([documentation](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_nearest.html) and [example](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-nearest/)). Since you are probably testing a point against a line you should have a look at [turf.point-on-line](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_point-on-line.html). In case you are working with polygons, you should check out
the [documentation](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_explode.html) and [example](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-explode/) of *turf.explode*, so you can actually access individual vertices from that polygon.

Turf.js is very easy to use and it works with any mapping library, as long as it supports GeoJSON. So, not a problem at all with [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to work without downloading any data

Comment: I'm working with GPX files and I need to adjust the recorded GPS path to the real ways, so this is the reason because I need to extract the nearest point in a road to my GPS point, which in OpenStreetMaps via the Overpass interface can be done via the 'around' query